# How to Capitalize text_field Words in Real Time Excluding Prepositions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to titleize/captialize words, like this [website](http://titlecapitalization.com), so that prepositions aren't included?

I'm not looking for you to list all the prepositions, but if you can just show how it can be done with a few like, "of, on, and" I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<%= f.text_area :name, id: "challenge-name" %>

<script> # This code capitalizes ALL words
  function makeTitle(slug) {
    var words = slug.split(' ');

    $.each(words, function(index, word){
        words[index] = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    });

    return words.join(' ');
  }

  $('#challenge-name').on('keyup', function(){ $(this).val( makeTitle($(this).val())) })
</script>
```

### UPDATE BASED ON FRED's ANSWER

```
function makeTitle(slug) {
  var preps = ['and', 'a', 'of', 'but', 'from'];
  return $.map(slug.split(' '), function(k, v) {
    return $.inArray(k.match(/\w*/g)[0], preps) >= 0 ? k : k[0].toUpperCase() + k.slice(1);
  }).join(' ');
}

$('#challenge-name').on('keyup', function(){ $(this).val( makeTitle($(this).val())) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to watch out for punctuation - this code takes punctuation into account:

```
def makeTitle(slug)
  preps = ['and', 'a']
  str.split(' ').map do |w| 
    preps.include?(/\w*/.match(w)[0]) ? w : w.capitalize 
  end.join ' '
end
```

I'll blame the late hour last nite - I didn't realize the OP wanted a jquery/javascript solution, so I created one in Ruby. I'll leave that in place in case any future viewer is looking for an answer in Ruby, but here is a JS method (using jQuery):

```
function makeTitle(slug) {
  var preps = ['and', 'a'];
  return $.map(slug.split(' '), function(k, v) {
    if(k){
        var word = k.match(/\w*/g)[0].toLowerCase();
      var letter = $.inArray(word, preps) >= 0 ? k[0].toLowerCase() : k[0].toUpperCase();
        return letter + k.slice(1);
    } else {
      return k;
    }
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use it as the body of `makeTitle` if you substitute `slug` for `str`, get rid of the string literal assignment to `str` and create your own `preps` list

Comment: Also take out the `return` statement. By default Ruby will return the result of the last expression if there is not an explicit return statement.

Comment: Hey Fred. Updated question with my attempt at your answer. I tried others, which I could include if you want, but that is the most basic one

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com - I was working late and didn't realize you were looking for a Javascript function! I've updated my answer, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: haha no worries buddy, I did put ruby and javascript in the tags. As to your update it is acting erratically for me where sometimes the propositions like, 'and' will capitalize anyway

Comment: now that I think about it, it might give an incorrect result if something like 'And' is already capitalized. Can you give me an example string where it's not behaving correctly?

Comment: As I can see all of them but sometimes a shorter word like `a` or `of` will stay lowercase

Comment: Please give me an example of an input string where it's not behaving correctly.

Comment: Updated question to account for updated version of your code. And per your example request. Let's say "test words - and, a, of, but, from". Now if I copy and paste that example then they are properly capitalized as such, "Test Words - and, a, of, but, from" , but if I write them into the `text_field` then it acts erratic by giving me, "Test Words - and, a, Of, But, From"

Comment: Ok - it was a matter of the case of the input - for example, when typing 'of', as the user types, 'o' is found in the list of preps, so gets uppercased to 'O'; when the user finishes typing the word, it reads 'Of', which doesn't match 'of'. So I updated to account for that case, and also made some changes to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks for walking me through this Fred. I appreciate this so much! Works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this in a different coding approach;

```js
var preps = ["of", "on", "and", "or", "in", "a", "the"],
      str = "the mother of the sea and a life in the depths of the ocean",
    words = str.match(/\b\w+\b/g);
   header = words.map((e,i) => preps.indexOf(e) == -1 || i === 0 ? e[0].toUpperCase()+e.slice(1) : e).join(" ");
console.log(header);
```

of course you may include what preposition you like to be kept as it is and exclude what not to the `preps` array.

As per your code; i would prefer to modify it as follows;

```
function makeTitle(slug) {
  var words = slug.match(/\b\w+\b/g),
      preps = ["of", "on", "and", "or", "in", "a", "the"];
  return words.map((e,i) => preps.indexOf(e) == -1 || i === 0 ? e[0].toUpperCase()+e.slice(1) : e).join(" ");
}
```

and this is the ES5 version which should be fine with Safari and older versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE which don't support JS arrows.

```js
function makeTitle(slug) {
  var words = slug.match(/\b\w+\b/g),
      preps = ["of", "on", "and", "or", "in", "a", "the"];
  return words.map(function(e,i) {
                     return preps.indexOf(e) == -1 || i === 0 ? e[0].toUpperCase()+e.slice(1) : e;
                   }).join(" ");
}

var s = makeTitle("the mother of the sea and a life in the depths of the ocean");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Thanks Redu for the help! How would I fit that in with my script if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: I have extended my answer to include a solution within the concept of your coding approaches.

Comment: Are you able to get that to work on your end? I can't get it to work. Once I type a word it wont let me click the spacebar

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: The `makeTitle()` function seems OK here. Keep in mind that it uses ES6 code though.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that @redu. It's not just normal javascript? I just plugged into my ruby on rails script and it didn't work. I played around with the punctuation, but it still didn't work. I'm not very good at javascript.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: Are you using Safari as browser..? If so i believe it won't recognize JS arrow functions which are part of ES6 specs. I guess i have to convert it ES5 then.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: Just added an ES5 version at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Redu but that wasn't the issue. Are you familar with ruby on rails? I think it is this line `$('#challenge-action-home').on('keyup', function(){ $(this).val( makeTitle($(this).val())) })` that probably needs to be adjusted to make your code chunk work.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: That line is jQuery.. Have you included jQuery at your script loading stages? and.. no sorry i haven't got any ruby experience at all.